# Can't access form from inside AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am trying to manually reset a form from inside an AngularJS controller but I can't access it using either `$scope`, or using `controllerAs`. When I log `$scope.SupportForm`, it returns `undefined`.

**HTML**

```
<form name="supportForm" id="supportForm" novalidate> 
  
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" model="$ctrl.formData.message" maxlength="5000" required></textarea>   

     <button type="submit" data-ng-click="$ctrl.submitForm($ctrl.formData)" data-ng-disabled="supportForm.$invalid">              
         Request support
     </button>

</form>
```

**Contoller**

```
function GeneralSupportController($scope, $state, $timeout, $stateParams, SupportService, $uibModal) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.formData = {};

    vm.submitForm = submitForm;

    function submitForm(data) {
         console.log('$scope.supportForm : ', $scope.supportForm)
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding ngModel to the form, but it also doesn't work.

**Question**

Any idea why the form isn't being assigned to the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form is assigned to scope in your code. (https://plnkr.co/edit/7eYvApaW36DrRmvK >> it works) I guess actually you have following:

```
<div ng-if="...">
  <form name=...
```

In this case form is assigned to nested scope of ng-if not controller scope. You have several solutions:

- pass form to submit function `$ctrl.submitForm(supportForm...` useful when u have several forms
- put form into controller `<form name="$ctrl.supportForm"` do it when u have one form